# Comparing types: Is 0 considered empty?

Tags: php

I am discovering that php is touchy when comparing types, especially when it comes to 0 because it is considered false and thus (I think) empty.

**Is a variable containing 0 considered empty?**

I have written a class in php that takes a stdClass and is able to manipulate it in different ways like edit, duplicate arrays, delete, etc. I have no idea of how the stdClass is made up. In the class I have a method that takes the address to the property in the stdClass and changes the property value to the new value and has to compare the property value with the new value at the end. Most of the values are entered or chosen by the user in the browser by selecting an array key. The key may be numerical or text.

In the method I have:

```
if (empty($address) || empty($new_value)){
        $this->last_error = "Unknown error";
        return false;
    }
```

empty($new_value) does not work when the value is 0. 0 in this case has been the array key. Is there a way to make this work for all possible situations.

Somewhere at the very end I have:

```
if ($new_value==$this->get_property ($address)) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

I think php is seeing this as: if (0==0){} Is this true?

This does not work when the property is set to zero.

Comment: mmm, if you've got that behaviour ... ever thinked of adding another OR in the if statement to check if the trimmed var length > 0 ? that can work a little

Comment: `empty` is `0` of any type (int, float, string), `''`, `null`, `false` or empty array, or undefined var. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: What way can I evaluate it to true when the value is 0. Even changing the 0 to a string does not work: if ($new_value==0){$new_value = '0';} I want to by pass the first part. How would isset() work here?

Comment: If I use: if ((empty($address) || empty($new_value)) && $new_value!=0) I am assuming php takes this to be: $new_value!=false The new value maybe -1 and may be of any data type.